# How do I find a specific function to this problem (finding maximum value)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

Well I have a very specific problem and I don't know how to approach it with math.

> You have a budget of $4800$ dollars. You can buy red flowers for $20$ dollars each and make profit of $35$ dollars each. Yellow flowers for $50$ dollars each and make profit of $80$ dollars from each. Blue flowers for $70$ dollars each and make profit of $110$ dollars from each. What is the maximum profit I can make with that budget?

I'm not looking for specific answer (although it can help), I want to know how can I solve this kind of problems. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Number of red flowers = a.
Number of yellow flowers = b.
Number of blue flowers = c.

Maximize: $35*a+80*b+110*c$

Under the constraint that $a*20 + b*50 + c*70 \leq 4800$.